# Is there a way to wrap asyncio Writer as FileWriter to pass the async writer to an existing API?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In my app I'd like to have an an async output channel to write data which is actually written by an existing API (https://github.com/ynqa/pandavro). Unfortunately the interface of the asyncio writer doesn't conform to the interface of the classic file-like writer.

Is there a way, like in Java, to somehow wrap the asyncio channel within a classic FileWriter interface? (w/o writing the wrapper by my own ...)

This is the code which I'd like to get running:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandavro as pdx
import asyncio


async def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Boolean": [True, False, True, False],
        "Float64": np.random.randn(4),
        "Int64": np.random.randint(0, 10, 4),
        "String": ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],
        "DateTime64": [pd.Timestamp('20190101'), pd.Timestamp('20190102'),
                       pd.Timestamp('20190103'), pd.Timestamp('20190104')]})

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 9090)

    pdx.to_avro(writer, df)

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found by myself is to write a simple wrapper class:

```py
class ChannelWriter:

    __delegate = None

    def __init__(self, delegate: asyncio.streams.StreamWriter):
        self.__delegate = delegate

    async def close(self):
        await self.__delegate.drain()
        return self.__delegate.close()

    @staticmethod
    def seekable():
        return False

    def write(self, value):
        self.__delegate.write(value)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```